# Raspberry Pi3 as BLE to PC handler

Tags: bluetooth

Good afternoon,

I'm new to Stack Exchange and posted this question in an area where it's probably not really the place to put it.  But this seems to be the right place.

A medical device I need to test is using BLE as part of its functionality.

Through Windows somehow, I need to connect to the device and execute some commands to make sure the BLE section is working correctly and also to write some calibration values into memory.

There is little to no BLE support using a PC running Windows that I'm aware of.

Could I use a Raspberry Pi 3 do be the "gateway?" I could set up the Raspberry PI to communicate with the BLE device using a dongle. Seems that this might not be the difficult part. (Is it?) I could send commands and requests to the Raspberry Pi and it in turn would handle the BLE portion.

I like the Raspberry PI idea because I can use LabVIEW with it.

Does this arrangement seem feasible? In terms of difficulty (subjective, I know) how difficult would you imagine this to be?

Thoughts? Opinions? Ideas?

Thank you,

Randy

Comment: It shouldn't be complicated using a pi, but the premise that windows doesn't support BLE is miles off. Adapters are cheap ([around £10](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Plugable-Bluetooth-Adapter-Raspberry-Compatible/dp/B009ZIILLI)).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Can you point me in the direction so I can learn about BLE working through Windows using the adapters?  I've got one too, but no underlying software it appears.  Maybe I'm missing something...???

Comment: I think [TI's BLE Device Monitor](http://goo.gl/EdPskO) looks like a good starting point. [Pygatt](http://goo.gl/tjVAQK) may be usable with your adapter. Windows 10 sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing). Windows 8.1 developer guide [here](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/ble-for-windows-81-part-i.html) and [here](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/ble-for-developers-in-windows-81-part-ii.html).